# In Wordpress Body Section there are two divs with different classes on them one of them is picking the css but other is not

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In Wordpress i have two div with different css classes on them but when i inspect it using firefox the css that i have written for the second is not shown in the css section and it is not picking up the css of that class.
here is my code :

```
<div class="innerContainer">
Inner Container

<div class="whiteBack">
    test container
                </div>

        </div>
```

its css is :

```
.whiteBack{
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color: pink;
}

.innerContainer{
      width:1170px;
   margin:0 auto;

    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: Here both css working. https://jsfiddle.net/oa3obbbL/

Comment: @ketan, the default CSS is probably overriding some of the custom css

Comment: Could also be that the HTML markup is invalid on the actual site. Be sure to run it through a validator. Firefox and Chrome's dev tools will try to correct invalid markup in their inspectors which can keep you in the dark. But invalid markup might explain why CSS rules aren't functioning like you'd expect. Or that you might need a clearfix... such as applying ` overflow: hidden;` to `.innerContainer` class.

Comment: Thanks its working now .